# Laravel 4: How to apply a WHERE condition to all queries of an Eloquent class?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to implement an "approved' state for a table I have, it's pretty straightforward, basically, if the row's approve column equals 1; that row should be retrieved, otherwise it shouldn't.

The problem is, now I have to go through the whole codebase and add a WHERE statement(i.e., function call) which is not only time consuming but also inefficient(if I ever want to remove that feature, etc.)

How can I do that? Is it as easy as adding `$this->where(..)` inside the Eloquent child class' constructor? Wouldn't that affect other CRUD operations? such as not updating an unapproved row?

Comment: You can take a look at http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators but I'm not sure how I'd implement it

Comment: @intelis Interesting, but sadly it looks useful for managing data representations(e.g., capitalizing first name) which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Maybe you could try overwriting ::all() method on the model? I don't know if it works but something like this..http://paste.laravel.com/P01

Comment: @intelis That might work, but most of my CRUD operations aren't using `all()`(mostly `find()`, `findOrFail()`, `where(..)->take()`, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing I found is [Eloquent query scope.](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes)

Even though it requires a minor change in my code(prefixing queries) it still gives me what I'm looking with great flexibility.

Here's an example:

Create a function within the Eloquent child class:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeApproved($query)
    {
        return $query->where('approved', '=', 1/*true*/);
    }

}
```

Then simply use it like this:

```
$approvedPosts = Post::approved()-><whatever_queries_you_have_here>;
```

Works perfectly. No ugly repeated WHERE function calls. easy to modify. Much easier to read(`approved()` makes much more sense than `where('approved', '=', 1)` )

Answer (score 22):

### The answer was given when there was no [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes) feature available.

You can override the main query, only for the `Post` model, like

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected static $_allowUnapprovedPosts = false;

    public function newQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::newQuery();

        if (!static::$_allowUnapprovedPosts) {
            $query->where('approved', '=', 1);
        } else {
            static::$_allowUnapprovedPosts = false;
        }

        return $query;
    }

    // call this if you need unapproved posts as well
    public static function allowUnapprovedPosts()
    {
        static::$_allowUnapprovedPosts = true;

        return new static;
    }
}
```

Now, simply use anything, but unapproved users won't appear in the result.

```
$approvedPosts = Post::where('title',  'like', '%Hello%');
```

Now, if you need to retrieve all posts even unapproved ones then you can use

```
$approvedPosts = Post::allowUnapprovedPosts()->where('title',  'like', '%Hello%');
```

### Update (Using the query scope):

Since, Laravel now provides [Global Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes), leverage that instead of this hacky solution, notice the date of this answer, it's too old and so much things changed by now.

```
// Using a local query scope
class Post extends Eloquent
{

    public function scopeApproved($query)
    {
        return $query->where('approved', 1);
    }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
$approvedPosts = Post::approved()->get();
```

Comment: The hacky solution you provide allows for accessing model variables where global scopes do not so it is still pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **global scope** for your need, docs for that are here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes

Good example is **SoftDeletingScope** which is applied to all queries by default on models which use **SoftDeletes** trait.