# Laravel Model Inser/delete/fetch always with a fixed where

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to have all of my Models to fetch/insert/update always with a fixed WHERE.

Like: where( 'site_id', '=', '1')

Without me having to go to all of my queries and change everything.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18680821/1581993

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a `BaseModel`:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public function newQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::newQuery();

        $query->where('site_id', 1);

        return $query;
    }

}
```

Extends all your models from it

```
class Post extends BaseModel {

}
```

And all your queries will have that `site_id` filter on it.

Comment: With this if I use Country::orderBy( 'order' )->get(); it doesn't work